# how to communicate with a web application on another server?

Tags: web-applications

I develop a web application and i use a web service of server A. And server A needs to communicate to another server B? How to communicate between server A and server B ?

An application running on the server side, how to communicate with a web application on another server? (There is no defined any web service on another server, because i use the other side's web service.)

Comment: what you mean "because i use the other side's web service" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about callbacks.

Callback is a notification from server to client(s). if any callback sends to all client, called "broadcasting".

ZeroC-ICE, WCF, .Net Remothing, Corba, and most middle-wares implementations are supports callback.

but if you using soap for your web-service , you cannot use callbacks.